# Java findAny with Optional

Tags: java

```
var a = Optional.of(new Detail().getContacts()) // Optional<Set<String>>
    .stream() // Stream<Set<String>>
    .findAny() // Optional<Set<String>>
    .map(o -> "withAnyVal")
    .orElse(null);
```

```
var b = Optional.of(new Detail().getContacts()) // Optional<Set<String>>
    .stream() // Stream<Set<String>>
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Stream<String>
    .findAny() // Optional<String>
    .map(o -> "withAnyVal")
    .orElse(null);
```

```
var c = Optional.of(new Detail())
    .map(Detail::getContacts)
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .findAny()
    .map(o -> "withAnyVal")
    .orElse(null);
```

Given: `getContacts()` is an empty collection.

Question:
Why does the first one return `"withAnyVal"`? Shouldn't it fail in `findAny` and go to `orElse` which returns null?

Only b and c give the correct values `null`.

Comment: When you say "`getContacts()` is empty", what do you mean? Is it an empty list? an empty optional? an empty stream? The first optional is likely not empty but contains one element (an empty collection for example). `Optional.of(Optional.empty())` is not empty. It is a valid optional that contains one element (the element being an empty optional).

Comment: In A, when you call findAny, you have a Stream containing 1 element, an empty list. That empty list is mapped to the string "withAnyVal".

Comment: What is the return type of `Detail#getContacts()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional.of(ArrayList<>)` will return `Optional<ArrayList<Object>>`.

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()

`Optional.stream()` - will return a stream of object if it exists. So, even if the list is empty, stream() will return a stream of empty list.

`findAny()` will return that list.

Change that `map(o -> "withAnyVal")` to `map(o -> "withAnyVal --> " + o)` to see what you are getting as `o`. You should get `[]` (empty list) as found any object.

`flatMap` results in making that stream of lists an empty stream (as the list element in the stream is empty, so flatMap results in empty stream).
Without `flatMap`, the stream has an empty list as an element.

Compare it with this:

```
int[][] ary = { {} };
System.out.println(ary.length);
```

This will return `1`. The array is not empty. The one element inside that array is an array and that array is empty.
If you flatten this array, you get `{}` - and hence 0 length. That's what `flatMap` does. After flattening, `findAny()` won't get anything.
Without `flatMap`, `findAny()` will get that array as it is the only element in the outer list.

Comment: thank you! your explanation and reference helped me understand the Optional.stream